# What html5 video types supported by smart phones and tablets?

Tags: android, iphone, html5-video

I'm adding `html5` video tags to our website to replace the Flash video player when a user is watching from a smart phone (Iphone, Android) or from a tablet that doesn't support Flash.

Is there one extension/video type that would be supported by all of those? (eg. `.mp4` and video/mp4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most detailed list I have seen recently is over here:

http://www.longtailvideo.com/html5/